# Gradle Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:4.0.12

Tags: gradle, groovy, spock

I had to delete my project and recreate it and when I did, I started getting the following error from my gradle build.

```
Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)

> Task :compileJava
Note: /home/thomas/workspace/util/src/main/java/com/heavyweightsoftware/util/EasyXmlParser.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

> Task :compileTestGroovy FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileTestGroovy'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':detachedConfiguration1'.
   > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:4.0.12.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/4.0.12/groovy-4.0.12.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :
   > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-ant:4.0.12.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-ant/4.0.12/groovy-ant-4.0.12.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :
   > Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-templates:4.0.12.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-templates/4.0.12/groovy-templates-4.0.12.pom
     If the artifact you are trying to retrieve can be found in the repository but without metadata in 'Maven POM' format, you need to adjust the 'metadataSources { ... }' of the repository declaration.
     Required by:
         project :

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.6.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 5s
3 actionable tasks: 3 executed
```

Google the error and found NOTHING... Here is the useful parts of my gradle build.

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy'
    id 'java'
}

...

apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'java'

...

dependencies {
    implementation (
            'org.apache.groovy:groovy-all:4.0.12',
            'jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:4.0.0',
    )

    testImplementation (
            'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.8.1',
            'org.spockframework:spock-core:2.4-M1-groovy-4.0',
            'io.github.joke:spock-mockable:2.3.1',
            'cglib:cglib-nodep:3.3.0'
    )

    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.8.1'
}

...

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I only use groovy for spock testing of my java classes.

Anyone see anything wrong?

Comment: Hi Thom. Groovy hasn't been in codehaus for a long time, so that part seems odd. Get the dependency tree and see what is trying to get it?

Comment: I suspect there's something that you're not showing us. Also why is groovy in the plugins, and then applied as a plugin?

Comment: @NathanHughes that confused me too. Will do

Comment: @tim_yates there are parts I didn’t show in the interest of brevity. I don’t remember why I did that anymore but it made it work.

Comment: For sure not. ;-) You first apply the plugins properly using the `plugins { ... }` block and then again using the legacy way that should not be used. But reapplying a plugin is just a no-op. So the second applying is just useless. Anything else would be very strange. Btw. if you only use Groovy for the Spock specs, why do you add it to your production dependencies? But besides that, easiest to find out is using a build `--scan`, otherwise maybe the `dependencies` and `dependencyInsight` tasks might help.

Comment: Is the project using springboot? I got something similar a couple weeks ago, upgrading to springboot 3 and using org.spockframework.spock-spring worked for me.

Comment: As you can see from his build script, he is not. ;-) He is simply using a 3 years old Gradle version that is not able to compile Groovy 4 code. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [release notes of Gradle 7.5](https://docs.gradle.org/7.5/release-notes.html#groovy4), you will see that this version added the ability to compile Groovy 4 code.

As you can see from your build's output, your Gradle version is 6.6.1.

So your Gradle version is simply too old to build Groovy 4 code.

If you want to use Groovy 4, you need to update Gradle to at least 7.5.